# Get information from current fragment in TableLayout

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I'm using TabLayout and ViewPager.I successfully integrated it and used from fragments.This is my mainTabActivity java class

```
public class MainTabActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private CustomTabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_simple_tabs);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (CustomTabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    findViewById(R.id.tab_ticket).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(MainTabActivity.this, TicketsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);

        }
    });
    findViewById(R.id.tab_main).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.e("BottomClickAction","BottomClickAction");

        }
    });

}
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new OneWayFragment(), "ONE");
    adapter.addFragment(new TwoFragment(), "ROUND");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

}
Also i have custom bottom bar.Now i try to explain my problem.In my fragments contains some elements,fro example spinners,Textviews or etc.My question is:How i get information from current fragment when i click bottom bar? I mean,spinner'data information,Textview's gettext or etc.
How i can solve my problem? Is it a possible to don't use static variables ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the fragment  `OneWayFragment` in viewpager like this:

```
public OneWayFragment getOneWayFragment() {
        return (OneWayFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(
                "android:switcher:" + R.id.viewPager + ":" + 0);
    }

public TwoFragment getTwoFragment() {
            return (TwoFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(
                    "android:switcher:" + R.id.viewPager + ":" + 1);
        }
```

You can access public method from `OneWayFragment` or `TwoFragment`  a get data you want.

For ex, create method getText from `OneWayFragment`:

```
public String getData() {
     return tv.getText().toString();
}
```

And in your `MainTabActivity`. For ex you click button has id `tab_main` and you get data from `OneWayFragment`.

```
findViewById(R.id.tab_main).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.e("BottomClickAction","BottomClickAction");
            OneWayFragment fragment = getOneWayFragment();
            if(fragment != null) {
               String data = fragment.getData();
             }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I know how to check current fragment in Viewpager.But in button click,how i can get information(textview's gettext or etc) @RoShan Shan

Comment: You mean `information` inside `OneWayFragment` or `TwoFragment`?

Comment: yep @RoShan Shan

Answer (score 0):

Create own method like  getFragmentData() in fragments. Access this method whenever you want. In your case:

1) take references of your fragment 
_oneWayaFrgament= new OneWayFragment()
 adapter.addFragment(_oneWayaFrgament, "ONE");

2) call _oneWayaFrgament.getFragmentData()

similarly apply your conditional logic on TwoFragment.

Please  call getFragmentData() by identifying current fragment.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can have public variables and methods in your fragments and then you can set and get your variables or call your methods from your activity.
for example in your fragments:

```
public String myString;
public Button someButton;
```

or

```
 public void fillMyTextView(){//some codes};
```

and in your activity you can call those methods or access your views like this:

```
myFragment.fillMyTextView("hello");
myFragment.someButton.setText("my btn");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you create singleton as state object(as you want as the state of the views, you can go with integer or short or byte for state marks memory wise) use as you want, and nullify once done usage. This way you can be access any data, in any fragment or activity, at any point of time. You can go with other implementations also like interface kinds as design and architectural way.But depends on the how important states are.